# Python generator send() strange behaviour

Tags: python, generator, send

While I try to understand the mechanism of generator's send() method, I encountered a strange behaviour in my example. (VS Code Python 3.10)

```
def MultipleOfThree():
    num  = 1
    while True:
        if num % 3 == 0:
           yield num
        num += 1

#test
iter = MultipleOfThree()

for m3 in iter:    
    print(m3)
```

This code is working as expected and prints

```
>>> 3,6,9,12,15,18,21.....
```

When I add the send() statement in for loop, and arrange the MultipleOfThree() func like below

```
def MultipleOfThree():
    num  = 1

    while True:
        if num % 3 == 0:
            i = yield num   
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1

#test
iter = MultipleOfThree()

for m3 in iter:    
    print(m3)
    iter.send(m3) #for simplicity send the m3 itself
```

it prints

```
>>> 3,9,15,21,27
```

I couldn't understand the mechanism of send() here, why escapes the for loop.
I study the subject from this page [How to Use Generators and yield in Python](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/#creating-data-pipelines-with-generators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize the generator:

```
iter = MultipleOfThree()
```

Get the first value:

```
m3= next(iter)
```

Then continue in a while loop:

```
while True:
    print(m3)
    m3 = iter.send(m3)
```

You wish to get the first value using `next(iter)` or `iter.send(None)` in order to reach the first multiple of three, without any input.

Then, you want to send back the input and continue from there using `iter.send(m3)`.

Overall code:

```
def MultipleOfThree():
    num  = 1
    while True:
        if num % 3 == 0:
            i = yield num   
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1

iter = MultipleOfThree()
m3= next(iter)
while True:
    print(m3)
    m3 = iter.send(m3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The generator makes a stop at each `yield` of some value. It continues after the value is consumed by calling `next` on the corresponding iterator. It continues until the next `yield` (or generator exit).

A `for` loop uses this iterator protocol to consume the yielded values one at a time and runs the loop body with each one.

A `send` is similar to `next`. It consumes a value, makes the generator to advance, but in addition to `next` It also sends a value to the generator. The sent value becomes the value returned by the `yield` (in the generator).

Your code is interacting with the generator at two places: in the `for` statement and in the `send` statement. But you are printing only one of the values, that's why you see only every second.

Add a `print` and you'll see all values again:

```
for m3 in iter:    
   print(m3)               # print 1 (yielded by for loop)
   print(iter.send(m3))    # print 2 (yielded by send)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I change the code "print(m3)\n
    iter.send(m3) " as  "print(iter.send(m3))"  but this time it prints the multiple of six. That is >>> 6,12,18,24...

Comment: @Tanzer There seems to be a small misunderstanding. You have removed the original `print`. I have updated the question to show the whole loop.

Comment: Oops, it was hard to me to guess the second print line :( Yes it gives the right output. Thank you again. I guess the actual answer seems more self describing in terms of the mechanism, and would be safer in bigger projects. Anyway thank you very much again.